# Como exibir numa página JSP os atributos de um objeto que foi passado numa lista

Tags: java, html, aplicação-web, jsp, spring-mvc

Estou trabalhando num projeto de Java Web, utilizando o framework Spring MVC.

Estou tendo dificuldade para exibir uma informação que vem de uma lista onde estão cadastrados analistas.

O nome do analista é exibido corretamente, já que nome é um atributo String de um objeto da classe Analista. Mas ao tentar exibir o CNPJ (String) do objeto Empresa (da classe Empresa), que nesse caso é um atributo de um objeto da classe Analista, o número do CNPJ não aparece.

```
<c:forEach var="analista" items="${listAnalistas}" varStatus="status">  
    <a>Nome do analista: <c:out value="${analista.nome}" /> </a>
    <a>CNPJ da empresa: <c:out value="${analista.empresa.cnpj}" /></a>
</c:forEach>
```

A lista é preenchida na classe Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
     public ModelAndView home() {
    List<Analista> listAnalistas = analistaDao.list();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/home/home");
    model.addObject("listAnalistas", listAnalistas);

    return model;
}
```

Existe alguma forma de exibir essa informação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi solucionado alterando o arquivo de configuração do Hibernate (hibernate.cfg.xml).

Tive que adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
<property name="enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Gabriel Polo**, passa a classe do seu controller no `forEach`

```
<c:forEach var="analista" items="${"classe do seu model".listAnalistas}" varStatus="status">  
    <a>Nome do analista: <c:out value="${analista.nome}" /> </a>
    <a>CNPJ da empresa: <c:out value="${analista.empresa.cnpj}" /></a>
</c:forEach>
```